# I need to perform a shuffle but I can't seem to let it work

Tags: python, python-3.x, shuffle

I am very new to python, and want to make a program that swaps the lower and upper case.

That is no problem, but I am having trouble with shuffling the words.

This is my code:

```
def swap_lower_upper(zin):
    print(zin.swapcase())
def shuffle(zin):
    import random
    lijst = list(zin)
    random.shuffle(lijst)
    print (lijst)
swap_lower_upper('Dit IS een test')
shuffle('Dit IS een test')
```

I've tried many things but I can't seem to let the shuffle work.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `list(zin)` splits the string into individual letters, then you need to join the letters after the shuffle with `print (''.join(lijst))`

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't an adequate problem specification. *How exactly* does it not work? What was the output you were expecting, and how does it differ from what you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the issue is that this is sorting letters overall rather than simply sorting the words. Rather than converting the string `zin` to a list by using the built-in `list` function, what you could do instead would be to split the string by spaces, using the `.split()` function of the string type. Then, after shuffling, for printing neatly, you could rejoin these words into a single string using the `.join()` function of the string type.

So something like this:

```
def swap_lower_upper(zin):
    print(zin.swapcase())

def shuffle(zin):
    import random
    lijst = zin.split(" ")
    random.shuffle(lijst)
    print (" ".join(lijst))

swap_lower_upper('Dit IS een test')
shuffle('Dit IS een test')
```